# cannot find symbol MapStyleOptions for android

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework

Hi i am not able to build android project.

```
android/app/src/main/java/plugin/google/maps/PluginMap.java:54:
```

error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MapStyleOptions;
                                        ^
  symbol:   class MapStyleOptions
  location: package com.google.android.gms.maps.model

I am using

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0"
```

if i update this latest

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0"
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
```

I am getting following error

```
Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
```

can anyone have a idea about

Comment: did you add `apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"` to the bottom of `build.gradle` ?

Comment: Please update the library to the latest version `17.0.0`

Comment: @Forntoh i had update the question